# how to copy files to a shared account in remote linux server

Tags: linux, copy, remote-server, account

We have a multiple user shared account in server, and every time I login in my own account in server through ssh and use `sudo -u shared_account -i` to login that account.

Now I want to copy some files to the shared account, and my current solution is:

1. copy the files to my own account in server by `scp` command
2. login to the server with my own account
3. login the shared account
4. copy the files in my own account to the folder of that shared account

Is there any way I can copy files directly from my local PC to the folder of shared account in the server?

OS of server is Linux, and my local PC is Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send an archive stream via `ssh` and `sudo`.

```
tar czf - file1 file2 file3 | ssh remote_system sudo -u shared_account tar xvzf -
```

Your comment to this answer shows that you have to enter your password when running `sudo`. Unfortunately this wasn't mentioned in the question.

If you can run programs that open a TCP port, e.g. `netcat` (`nc`) as the shared user you could combine this with `tar` (or `cpio`) to transfer files directly using the shared user's permissions and environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I didn't run the cmd successfully, but to find similar way: `echo $password | ssh $remote_server sudo -S -u shared_account "cp /home/$my_account/path/to/files /home/shared_account/path/of/target/dir"`. Running this cmd in local pc, it can sudo as the shared account in remote server and run cp cmd in server, so that I can run cmd locally to copy files to the home dir of the shared account in remote server. In this way, I can write shell scripts in my Mac to cover all 4 steps of my current solution without really login to the remote server.